# Does a class template's requires clause have to be repeated outside member definitions?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-concepts

When the member of a class template that uses the `requires` clause is defined outside the class, `gcc` does not complain if `requires` is not specified, whereas `clang` does.

Consider the code snippet below:

```
#include <concepts>

template<typename Container>
    requires std::integral<typename Container::value_type>
class Foo {
public:
    void func();
};

template<typename Container>
void Foo<Container>::func()
{}
```

The compilation using `gcc` does not complain.

While `clang` reports the following error:

```
❯ clang++ -std=c++2a test.cpp
test.cpp:10:1: error: requires clause differs in template redeclaration
template<typename Container>
^
test.cpp:4:19: note: previous template declaration is here
    requires std::integral<typename Container::value_type>
                  ^
1 error generated.
```

If I change the definition as below:

```
template<typename Container>
    requires std::integral<typename Container::value_type>
void Foo<Container>::func()
{}
```

now `clang` does not complain.

Output from `gcc --version`:

```
gcc (GCC) 10.2.0
```

Output from `clang --version`:

```
clang version 10.0.1 
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

Is this a bug to be reported?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A bug should be filed for GCC, because it accepts the code, even though the declaration of the member outside the class does not have an equivalent template-head.

> **[temp.class]**
>
> [3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.class#3) When a member function, a member class, a member enumeration, a
> static data member or a member template of a class template is
> **defined outside of the class template definition**, the member definition is defined as **a template definition in which the
> *template-head* is equivalent to that of the class template** ([temp.over.link]).
>
> **[temp.over.link]**
>
> [6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.over.link#6) Two template-heads are equivalent if their
> template-parameter-lists have the same length, corresponding
> template-parameters are equivalent and are both declared with
> type-constraints that are equivalent if either template-parameter is
> declared with a type-constraint, and **if either template-head has a
> requires-clause, they both have requires-clauses** and the
> corresponding constraint-expressions are equivalent.

The equivalence of templates-heads requires that both have an equivalent requires clause. Omitting it entirely breaks the equivalence.

Comment: filed here: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=96830

Answer (score 2):

From [[temp.mem.func]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.mem.func#1) [extract, **emphasis** mine]:

> A member function of a class template may be defined outside of the
> class template definition in which it is declared. [*Example:*
>
> A **constrained member function** can be defined out of line:
>
> ```
> template<typename T> concept C = requires {
>   typename T::type;
> };
>
> template<typename T> struct S {
>   void f() requires C<T>;
>   void g() requires C<T>;
> };
>
> template<typename T>
>   void S<T>::f() requires C<T> { }  // OK
> template<typename T>
>   void S<T>::g() { }                // error: no matching function in S<T>
> ```
>
> — *end example*]

taking note particularly the final example of the (non-normative) text.

Thus, Clang is correct to reject whereas GCC is wrong to accept the first program as the out-of-line definition

> ```
> template<typename Container>
> void Foo<Container>::func() {}
> ```

does not match any function in `Foo<Container>`.

<sub>(I have not yet found an open GCC bug report for this)</sub>

Comment: It's not ill-formed NDR. The templates heads in the OP's example are not functionally equivalent. That's diagnosable.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Ah you are right - the not-even-functional equivalence is the place to stop (not down the equivalence rabbit hole, as I did). Thanks.