# Why does an out-of-class member template definition need a repetition of its declaration 'requires-clause'

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++-concepts

This is related to the following question: [Does a class template's requires clause have to be repeated outside member definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63628752/does-a-class-templates-requires-clause-have-to-be-repeated-outside-member-defin)

In other words, given the code for the following templated struct `A`, the *requires-clause* needs to be repeated for the `foo()` function definition (per the standard paragraphs quoted in the linked question above)

```
template <typename T>
    requires std::integral<T> //'requires-clause'
struct A
{
    void foo();
};

template <typename T>
    requires std::integral<T> //This 'requires-clause' is required by the standard to be reiterated
void A<T>::foo()
{
    //
}

//Specialisations do not require explicit 'requires-clause'
template <>
void A<int>::foo()
{
    //
}

//Specialisation with a type that does not meet the constraint raises a compile-time error
template <>
void A<double>::foo() //Not allowed because std::integral(double) == false
{
    //
}
```

But I don't know why it is necessary to repeat the *requires-clause* for the specific class members described in [[temp.class]\3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.class#3). I can't think of a situation where this requirement would make a difference. In the example above, if the *requires-clause* is with the struct definition, any attempt to instantiate anything that isn't an integral type would not compile, so whether `A<T>::foo()` also requires that `std::integral<T> == true` is irrelevant. AFAIK it also makes no difference during specialisation because any attempt to specialise to a different type from an integral (as in this example) leads to an compilation error.

However, I'm sure that there are legitimate reasons for including this requirement in the standard - can anybody demonstrate a situation where the absence of this `requires-clause` on the definition would cause an issue?

Comment: How about adding a [language-lawyer] tag?

Comment: You already found the "an answer from a reputable source" as you directly refer to it. The reasoning is not described in the docs. How should anyone answer? BTW: The reasoning why you have to repeat it, seems natural for me as you can't  "extend" the allowed types by a later "specialization" for an type restricted template.

Comment: I am not sure there is a hidden reason except implementation difficulties on the compiler side. For example in c++ 11 there where no reason to not have auto on function returns but it happend for 3 years.

Comment: I don't know much about C++20 concepts (yet) but could it be possible that there are several templates `A<T>` defined that only differ in their `requires` clause (and with template parameter specializations assigned to the most narrow requirements)? In that case you'd have to repeat it so the compiler can map the `foo` definition to the right template.

Comment: I think the reason is readability tbh

Comment: "Requires" is needed on the first two blocks because you are still defining the template. The specializations do not require "requires" because they are describing how the template works with certain types, but the template is already clearly defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the last section of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints you can specialize templates not only on parameters but also on their constraints. Like parameter specializations the standard defines also a partial ordering of constraints, such that a template specialization might be more constrained than another.

So, for example, you may have a more constrained specialization of your template `A`:

```
template <typename T>
    requires std::unsigned_integral<T>
struct A
{
    void foo();
};
```

With a different implementation of the element function `foo`:

```
template <typename T>
    requires std::unsigned_integral<T>
void A<T>::foo()
{
    // different implementation of foo() relying on T being unsigned integral
}
```

So, without the repeated requires clause in the definitions of both versions of `A<T>::foo` the compiler would not know to which specialization of `A` the defined `foo` would belong.

Comment: @NotAProgrammer Thanks for the bounty.

Comment: Actually, I issued the bounty and I accepted it :) notaprogrammer can also "accept" the answer giving you another 15rep. I hope he does that.

Comment: Could you give an example of how this works for classes? I got the more constrained requires clauses to work with templated free functions (which I didn't know you can do, thanks!) but more constrained class function templates always complain about the requires clause not matching the initial declaration.

Comment: If you join your code (except the specializations) and my code it should be an example although I haven't tested it. If this or your own example doesn't work, please open a new question for that and mention the compiler (version) you tried. As C++20 is quite new it could also be that your compiler (version) did not implement it yet.